# error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘void* (*)(void*)’ - pthreads

Tags: c++, linux, g++, pthreads

```
anisha@linux-y3pi:~> g++ conditionVarTEST.cpp -Wall

conditionVarTEST.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
conditionVarTEST.cpp:33:53: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘void* (*)(void*)’
conditionVarTEST.cpp:33:53: error:   initializing argument 3 of ‘int pthread_create(pthread_t*, const pthread_attr_t*, void* (*)(void*), void*)’
conditionVarTEST.cpp:34:53: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘void* (*)(void*)’
conditionVarTEST.cpp:34:53: error:   initializing argument 3 of ‘int pthread_create(pthread_t*, const pthread_attr_t*, void* (*)(void*), void*)’
```

---

Line number 33 is this:

```
pthread_create (&A, NULL, (void *) &functionA, NULL);
```

---

Declaration of `functionA` is this:

`void functionA (void*);`

---

Its definition is:

```
void functionA (void* argA)
{
    while (1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock (&mutexA);

        if (count < 0)
        {
            pthread_cond_wait (&conditionVariableA, &mutexA);
        }
        else
        {
            // Do something.
            std :: cout << "\nTime to enjoy!";
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutexA);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you look at the [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_create) you will see that the function argument is

```
void *(*start_routine) (void *)
```

That is, a pointer to a function which takes one `void *` argument and returns `void *`.

To get rid of your errors, change your function to return `void *`, and pass it without type-casting it. The return from the thread function can be a simple `return NULL` if you don't care about the value.

Comment: I am sorry for not looking at the man page. I followed this: http://www.amparo.net/ce155/thread-ex.html This gave me errors.

Comment: @AnishaKaul If you get a compilation error about arguments to a function, then it could be helpful to look at the manual page for that function to make sure that you get the arguments right.

Answer (score 4):

`(void *) &functionA` will cast your function pointer `functionA` which is of type  `void (*)(void*)` to a simple `void*`. The later can't be converted to the first again, so the compiler reports an error. This is one of the reasons why you shouldn't use C-style casts.

Use `pthread_create (&A, NULL, functionA, NULL);` instead.

Also, the return type of a thread function should be `void*`, not `void`. So change `void functionA(void*)` to `void* functionA(void*)`.

Comment: that gives me: `error: invalid conversion from ‘void (*)(void*)’ to ‘void* (*)(void*)’`

Comment: More generally, `void*` is a pointer to data, `void (*)(void*)` is a pointer to a function.  There is _no_ legal conversion between the two types.

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
pthread_create (&A, NULL, functionA, NULL);
```

instead of casting.

Also the function you use to pass to pthread_create should return a `void*` so to avoid any problems later, consider changing the function signature to accomodate this.

Answer (score 3):

And as you are using a C++ compiler, you should use a function with C binding, as pthread_create expects a C function:

```
extern "C" void* functionA (void*);
```

C++ and C may have the same calling conventions on your current platform, but there is no guaranty, that this will be the case on other platforms or will be so in the future.